# Why this script is so slow when creating a random list

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to generate a random directory structure with 10s of thousands of directories, but this script takes way too long. Is it the recursive call to CreateDir that is causing the slowness. I using a file to store the the directory list, so I can create all the directories at once AND because I could not figure out how to use an array.  For example, it took 3 minutes for 1200 directories.

```sh
Clear-Host
$ParentDir             = 'c:\a\'
$MinNumberOfLeaves     = 2
$MaxNumberOfLeaves     = 10
$MaxDepth              = 5
$MinDepth              = 2

Function CreateDirName{
    $fRandomNames   = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()
    # Get-Random -Count ([int]::MaxValue)) Randomizes the entire list of commands
    $fRandomNames   += (((Get-Command) | Select-Object -Property Name).Name | `
                    Where-Object {($_ -inotmatch ":") -and ($_ -inotlike "")} )
    $fRandomName    = ($fRandomNames | Get-Random -Count 1) -replace("-","")
Return $fRandomName
}
Function CreateDir{
    Param(
            $fParentDir,
            $fMinNumberOfLeaves = 2,
            $fMaxNumberOfLeaves = 3,
            $fMaxDepth          = 3,
            $fMinDepth          = 2,
            $fRandomDepth       = 2   
    )    
    
    For($d=1;$d -le ($fRandomDepth);$d++)
    {
        $fNumOfLeaves = Get-Random -Minimum $fMinNumberOfLeaves -Maximum  $fMaxNumberOfLeaves
        #$fNumOfLeaves = 4
        For($l=1;$l -le $fNumOfLeaves;$l++)
        {
            $fSubDirName    = CreateDirName
            $fFullDirPath   = $fParentDir + '\' + $fSubDirName 
            $fFullDirPath  | Out-File -Append -FilePath c:\a\Paths.txt -Encoding ascii
            #New-Item -Path $fFullDirPath -ItemType Directory
            $SubDirs        = CreateDir -fParentDir $fFullDirPath  -fRandomDepth ($fRandomDepth-1)
            Out-Null
        }
        Out-Null
    }

    Out-Null
}
"Dirs"| Set-content  c:\a\Paths.txt -Force -Encoding ascii
$RandomDepth = Get-Random -Minimum $MinDepth -Maximum  $MaxDepth
#$RandomDepth = 3
CreateDir -fParentDir $ParentDir  -fRandomDepth $RandomDepth 
Out-Null
```

Comment: I would say there is overhead everywhere in your code, not only in the recursive call

Comment: `Out-File -Append` is very slow, when using it in a loop, because it opens and closes the file for every loop iteration, which is expensive.

Comment: the biggest thing as of now is the call to `get-command`.. this takes 3 seconds on my machine. you can set the output of get command to a $global: scoped variable and check if that is present before next iteration.

if you want a actual random name, you can use `[System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName().replace('.','')`

Comment: @Withholm how do you increase the number of characters in the [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName().replace('.','') I could not find any documentation around it

Comment: @Gt3pccb you cant. its just used to generate a random file name without any notion of sizing or anything... you can however join several of these together to get a longer name if you want

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are many aspects of your approach that makes this script slow.
I think is a great learning opportunity.

First, let's address your 'CreateDirName' function.
The current workflow is:

- Create a new ArrayList
- Get a list of ALL commands, Select the property 'Name', then select 'Name' again '().Name', use a post filter for strings that don't match ':' and it's not like ''.
- Pipe the result to 'Get-Random' and use '-replace' to remove '-'

First, remove the unnecessary 'Select-Object'. You can expand the property 'Name' like this: '(Get-Command).Name'.
Then let's look at your filter. 'Where-Object', by itself is costly, but you make it worse by using '-inotmatch' and '-inotlike'.
'-match' operators use RegEx.
'-like' operators works with wildcards, which is also costly.
Since a string is an array of characters, we can use '.Contains()' to filter ':', and to avoid empty or null values we can use 'String.IsNullOrEmpty()'.
'-replace' also uses regex, we can replace it with '.Replace()'. (Pun not intended).
Suddenly, our code looks like this:

```
$fRandomNames = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()
$fRandomNames += ((Get-Command).Name | Where-Object { !$_.Contains(':') -and ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_) })
$fRandomName = ($fRandomNames | Get-Random -Count 1).Replace('-', '')
```

Now, still on this function, since arrays are immutable objects, the '+=' operator creates a new array to support the object's size.
To improve that, we can use ArrayList.AddRange().
And since we are talking performance, using the pipeline always adds cost, so let's borrow LINQ from C#, and change this 'Where-Object'.
And now we have:

```
$fRandomNames = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()
$fRandomNames.AddRange([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where((Get-Command).Name, [Func[object, bool]] { param($c) !$c.Contains(':') -and ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($c) }).ToList())
$fRandomName = (Get-Random -InputObject $fRandomNames -Count 1).Replace('-', '')
```

Getting better. I ran some tests with these options, and we got a 36% improvement.

[image]

Now let's attack the main function body.
You don't need to call 'Get-Command' every time, you can get the list and re-use it for further operations.
With this, we can ditch 'CreateDirName' completely, which avoids a memory lap, and contributes to our performance.

We can also avoid using 'for' loops, specially if you don't need the index number.
Let's use a 'do-while' loop instead.

Before I paste the next code session, let's look at how you write your data into the file.
You are calling 'Out-File' in every single operation.
That involves:

- Getting the string and pass it to the pipe line.
- Check if the file and directory exists.
- Open a file stream to write data.
- Write data.
- Close the stream.
- Dispose of unmanaged objects.

We can store the results in another ArrayList and write everything at the end.
And now we have:

```
$fRandomNames = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()
$fRandomNames.AddRange([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where((Get-Command).Name, [Func[object, bool]] { param($c) !$c.Contains(':') -and ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($c) }).ToList())
    
$newPathList = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()

$currentDepth = 0
do {
        
        $leafNumber = 0
        do {
            
                $newPathList.Add("$fParentDir\$((Get-Random -InputObject $fRandomNames -Count 1).Replace('-', ''))")
                New-CustomDirectory -fParentDir $fFullDirPath -fRandomDepth ($fRandomDepth - 1)
                $leafNumber++

        } while ($leafNumber -lt (Get-Random -Minimum $fMinNumberOfLeaves -Maximum  $fMaxNumberOfLeaves))

        $currentDepth++

} while ($currentDepth -lt $fRandomDepth)
```

Last thing I want to talk about is 'Out-File' and 'Out-Null'.
We now the steps for writing a file, why don't we use pure .NET instead?
And what's with all the 'Out-Null's?????
Every 'Out-Null' implies a cost. You should consider never using 'Out-Null'.
Instead, use $result = $null, or [void]$result.DoWork().
And you only need to do it once, at the main function call.
Let's tackle the file writing first.
Ran another sample to show you the benefits of using pure .NET:

[image]

And at the end, we have something like this:

```
$ParentDir             = 'c:\a\'
$MaxDepth              = 5
$MinDepth              = 2

function New-CustomDirectory {
    Param(
            $fParentDir,
            [int]$fMinNumberOfLeaves = 2,
            [int]$fMaxNumberOfLeaves = 10,
            [int]$fMaxDepth          = 3,
            [int]$fMinDepth          = 2,
            [int]$fRandomDepth       = 2   
    )

    $fRandomNames = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()
    $fRandomNames.AddRange([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where((Get-Command).Name, [Func[object, bool]] { param($c) !$c.Contains(':') -and ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($c) }).ToList())
    
    $newPathList = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()

    $currentDepth = 0
    do {
        
        $leafNumber = 0
        do {
            
            $newPathList.Add("$fParentDir\$((Get-Random -InputObject $fRandomNames -Count 1).Replace('-', ''))")
            New-CustomDirectory -fParentDir $fFullDirPath -fRandomDepth ($fRandomDepth - 1)
            $leafNumber++

        } while ($leafNumber -lt (Get-Random -Minimum $fMinNumberOfLeaves -Maximum  $fMaxNumberOfLeaves))

        $currentDepth++

    } while ($currentDepth -lt $fRandomDepth)
    
    $stream = [System.IO.File]::AppendText('C:\a\Paths.txt')
    $stream.Write($newPathList)
    $stream.Dispose()
}

"Dirs"| Set-content  c:\a\Paths.txt -Force -Encoding ascii
$RandomDepth = Get-Random -Minimum $MinDepth -Maximum  $MaxDepth
[void](New-CustomDirectory -fParentDir $ParentDir -fRandomDepth $RandomDepth)
```

**DISCLAIMER!** I didn't study what your script does and didn't test my version's output. This was only a block performance study.
You might need to change it to suit your needs.

Source:

- [PowerShell scripting performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations?view=powershell-7.3)
- [High performance PowerShell with LINQ](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/high-performance-powershell-linq/)
- [Under the stairs: Performance with PowerShell](https://tfl09.blogspot.com/2011/11/performance-with-powershell.html)

Hope it helps!
Happy scripting!

Comment: One more question, how would you speed up the Select-Object  -Unique? It is painfully slow when parsing millions

Comment: the Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'ToList'.
At line:2 char:5
+     $fRandomNames.AddRange([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where((Get-Comma ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct in pointing out multiple issues.  But the first and primary needed change is removing these lines from the CreateDirName function and placing them near the top of the script:

```
    $fRandomNames   = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()
    # Get-Random -Count ([int]::MaxValue)) Randomizes the entire list of commands
    $fRandomNames   += (((Get-Command) | Select-Object -Property Name).Name | `
                    Where-Object {($_ -inotmatch ":") -and ($_ -inotlike "")} )
```

The `(Get-Command)` takes about 11 seconds on my computer, and calling it over and over again is insane!  Build the `$fRandomNames` arraylist when the script starts, and use CreateDirName to only pick a random name from the already created `$fRandomNames` arraylist.